# Semantic html5 document flow

Tags: html

I am using the following document flow for a one-page web site.

```
<body>

<div>

  <section>
    <header>
      <h1></h1>
    </header>
  </section>

  <section>
    <header>
      <h2></h2>
    <header>
    <article>
      <h3></h3>
    </article>
  </section>

  <section>
    <header>
      <h2></h2>
    </header>
    <article>
      <h3></h3>
    </article>
  </section>

  <footer>
    <h2></h2>
  </footer>

</div>


</body>
```

I have a few questions

1)  is The way I have used heading tags correct (one h1 tag in one page section and others have headings starting with h2 and goes to h6) or do I have to start heading with h1 in each section.

eg

```
  <section>
    <header>
      <h1></h1>
      <h2></h2>
    <header>
    <article>
      <h1></h1>
      <h2></h2>
    </article>
  </section>
```

2) When I check this code using Chrome's html5 document outliner extension it shows that footers h2 tag as entire documents heading instead of showing one and only h1 tag.

[image]

Please excuse me for my bad English. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: I saw this a few years ago. It may answer part of your question. It's in en-us: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIn5qJKU8VM

Comment: @JezD Thanks alot my friend.. It helps me a lot :)

Comment: Anyone? I still have my second problem

Comment: Can you put it on jsfiddle so we can see it in action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A footer is not sectioning content.
So when you use a H2 tag, in this case it will form a section in the main document.
You should make a section as footer and use footer within if you would choose to do so.
The 'problem' with HTML5 sectioning is that it lets you do a lot of things that are 'right'.

Additionally: what you have now may be right, if the footer is related to the whole page.
It's just a matter of what you want to happen in the outline.
Obviously, you can't use H2 if you don't want a new section to begin.

More info: [Mozilla's description of a footer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/footer)

Comment: +1. IMHO, the outline algorithm is not fit for purpose. There are too many situations in which the outline generated is surprising, and too little control of the mark-up to make it fixable.